# Doesn't Boot after 11.04 install

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

after I install it from a burned cd into my vaio laptop (the process is normal,ubuntu boots off CD) after a full install, I restart, shows viao screen then goes straight to the black screen with the cursor and stays that way

Comment: A question, did you work fine when you click in the liveCD the option "try ubuntu"?
If it is yes:
1-Try to reinstall again
2-If it still not works, can you go into recovery mode? An option in the boot (if you don't know how do this, tell me)

Comment: Does `Ctrl+Alt+F3` work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Try recovery mode. If it doesn't work, reinstall the operating  system.